# How Do I Debug An Angular 7 Library in Visual Code

Tags: node.js, angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, angular-library

Is it possible to use Visual Studio Code Debugger to debug an Angular Library that has been linked using npm link? Very specifically I am wondering if I can link the debugger to my library's TypeScript Code (not the built js code).

My debugger works fine for the application I am running through the VS Code, however my linked library breakpoints are never hit.

From the research I have done I believe I understand why this is happening (the app using the library does not have the source, it only has the compiled code within node_modules) however I cannot figure out or find any details on how to debug.

Here is an overview of what I have done:

- Angular 7 library built into dist folder.
- I ran `npm link` within the dist folder
- I ran `npm link @my/test-lib` in my application, the library shows up in node_modules and the application is able to use it just fine
- in angular.json: sourceMap is true, preserveSystemlinks is true, aot is false, vendorSourceMap is true
- tsconfig.json sourceMap is true, enableResourceInlining is true
- vscode launch.json has runtimeArgs set to --preserve-symlinks and --preserve-symlinks-main

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm posting just to provide a clearer example to @SyncingDisks solution:

You actually don't need the full path, ${workspaceFolder} would do the job also:

```
"webpack:///ng://angular-reporting/lib/*": "${workspaceFolder}/projects/angular-reporting/src/lib/*"
```

which would fit in launch.json as follows:

```
 {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            "webpack:///ng://angular-reporting/lib/*": "${workspaceFolder}/projects/angular-reporting/src/lib/*"
        },
}
```

Don't forget to add `--vendorSourceMap` to ng serve which would become:

```
ng serve --vendorSourceMap
```

**Update**:

for Angular 7 and higher update the "angular.json" file instead of adding "--vendorSourceMap" to "ng serve":

```
"serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "sourceMap": {
          "scripts": true,
          "styles": true,
          "vendor": true
        },
        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Fine tune your launch.json based on the `sourceMapPathOverrides`. Excerpt from mine:

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
     "webpack:///ng://<<your-awesome-lib>>/lib/*": "C:/<<full path to your library wrapper app>>/projects/<<your-awesome-lib>>/src/lib/*"
 },
```

Comment: I tried various combinations of paths to try and get the debugger working and it still does not seem to work for the library. I am not sure what I am missing.

The library I want to link debugger to:

C:\dev\git_repo\my-components\projects\abc\shared-components
C:\dev\git_repo\my-components\projects\abc\shared-components\src (with public_api.ts)
C:\dev\git_repo\my-components\projects\abc\shared-components\src\lib (the html/ts files)

Consuming App:
C:\dev\git_repo\my-experience\my-ui-application
C:\dev\git_repo\my-experience\my-ui-application\.vscode\launch.json

Comment: It might also be worth noting that my library is scoped:

@abc/shared-components

Comment: Are you serving it with --vendorSourceMap --source-map=true?

Comment: So it should be: 
`..."sourceMapPathOverrides": {
     "webpack:///ng://<<your-awesome-lib>>/lib/*": "C:/dev/git_repo/my-components/projects/abc/shared-components/src/lib/*"
 }...`. And `<<your-awesome-lib>>` as referenced in your `package.json`. I will check with a scoped lib this weekend.