# How to debug an Angular 9 Library in VSCode

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

I'm developing a library called `@nf-ionic/common`.
The library is used in a project called `example-app`.

In the development phase I'm linking `@nf-ionic/common` with `npm link @nf-ionic/common`.
This works just fine and I can build `example-app` without any problems.

Now I want to debug `@nf-ionic/common` in `example-app` over `VSCode`. Unfortunately, I'm not able to do so.

What I tried so far:

- Add `sourceMap: { "vendor": true }` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690465/vendorsourcemap-deprecated-in-angular-cli-7-2)
- Add `justMyCode: false` in my `.vscode/launch.json` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025332/how-to-debug-external-library-code-in-visual-studio-code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980448/how-to-disable-just-my-code-setting-in-vscode-debugger). It seems like this option isn't even available in `.vscode/launch.json`.
- Add `"sourceMapPathOverrides": {...}` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188658/how-do-i-debug-an-angular-7-library-in-visual-code)

I'm able to debug the library in my browser, when setting the `sourceMap: { "vendor": true }` but not in `VSCode`.

**Work environment:**

- `@nf-ionic/common`: `Angular 9.1.9` library project created like described [here](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)
- `example-app`: `Ionic 5.1.1` with `Angular 9.1.6`

Comment: still having this problem with Angular 13. Did you find a solution? Tried all options with sourceMapPathOverrides I could find, but none worked. I can see the library linked in the browser under webpack:///node_modules/projects/<<library-name-withouz-scope>>/src/lib