# How do I skip libraries when debugging angular code in VS code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I have an angular project I am attempting to debug however, it steps into @angular/core and ts-lib when I am going through the debugging process. These are huge files with a lot of steps. Is there a way to skip external code?

this is my launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200/silverlakeopc",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "skipFiles": ["!**/node_modules/**"]
    }
]
```

}

When I added the "skipFiles" line it now skips over ALL my code. I just want to skip over external libraries.

I have tried:

1. [how do I skip external code when debugging in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556495/how-do-i-skip-external-code-when-debugging-in-vs-code)
2. [How Do I Debug An Angular 7 Library in Visual Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188658/how-do-i-debug-an-angular-7-library-in-visual-code)
3. [How to exclude node modules and node internals from VS --debugger-- ??](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/620)

**Here is a screenshot of my workspace structure:**
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the Chrome Debugging extension in VS Code, I made my `launch.json` look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200/**",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 9222,
            "skipFiles": [
              "node_modules/**/*.js",
              "runtime.js",
              "polyfills.js",
              "vendor.js",
              "analytics.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And it seems to do the trick. Most third party code would be in vendor.js I believe.

Comment: This works the best. I was actually ignoring the node modules here. I forgot that Webpack bundles all of these dependencies and sticks them into a single file. For that sir. you deserve the win

Answer (score 0):

You can't set it in VSCode but here is a workaround named `Blackboxing`:

It is a tool that you can use to skip library check for debugging in browser.

To set In Firefox [check out here](http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/ignoring-library-code-while-debugging-in-chrome/)

To set In Chrome [check out here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQO4J.png)

From Chrome v75 and later there is a section named `Blackboxing` in console settings that you can set scripts there and also it's name is changed to `Ignore List` in earlier releases.

[image]